# My Minecraft Folder not showing up on macOS

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, macos

I'm trying to access my Minecraft folder to install a resource pack, however the folder doesn't seem to exist. I've looked in "Application Support" and it's not there. I've tried executing commands in terminal to show hidden files. I've tried typing in "~/Library/Application Support/minecraft" in the search bar and the folder does show up, however when I click on it finder crashes and displays the message "The Application Finder is not open anymore".

Comment: Have you tried clicking the button in the game's menu to show the folder of a selected world?

Answer (score 0):

On recent versions of Minecraft Java, you can click "Open Resource Pack Folder" on `Options > Resource Packs...` as a way to open your Minecraft folder.

This is applicable on Windows, macOS and Linux.

[image]

Comment: When I click the button absolutely nothing happens... I assume my computer is having trouble locating the folder for some reason?